# how to change Zimbra send Button functionality?

Tags: javascript, java, zimbra, zimlet

I am using zimbra 8 to send mails.I have a one new requirement that is, When send button is triggered, it should validate some to,cc or bcc fields for one type of mail based on sender user account.
For this what is the way.
Can I use zimlets or can i change direclty any js files.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its a setting single-minded by the bureaucrat. If the feature is enabled for your account, the send button will change to a menu button, where you can open the menu and choose Send Later.